# Find a string in a file and then find the first line above containing another string with bash?

Tags: awk, grep

How can I find a string in a file, then find the first instance of a line that contains 'srv' that precedes it.

I have been looking at Tac and sed, but have been unsuccessful at getting it to work right.

Output file to search looks like

```
srv-test-1
a1
A3
srv-test-2 
a1
b1
b2
B3
B4
```

The code prompts the user for the string they are looking for and stores it to a variable.

I am able to find the users request using

```
tac file | grep $requested
```

if the user requests b1, I would like it to return

```
b1 found on srv-test-2
```

and likewise if requesting a1 it would return

```
a1 found on srv-test-1
a1 found on srv-test-2
```

I have the line in the bash script below

```
awk -v rs="$requested" -v IGNORECASE=1 '/^srv/{ line = $0; next } $0 ~ rs { print rs" found on " line }' file
```

It does not seem to be ignoring the case. If I put the a1 to search it finds it perfectly. But if I enter A1 it does not. I have also tried this method. I did also try hard coding the `rs` variable to make sure it was not just a variable being passed issue.

```
awk -v rs="$requested" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/^srv/{ line = $0; next } $0 ~ rs { print rs" found on " line }' file
```

It also needs the inverse, such that if the user enters b4 it finds B4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much more easy with `awk`, unlike `grep` which doesn't allow you to split a line on a given delimit character or mark lines containing a pattern for latter use. Awk is your typical Swiss Army<sup>TM</sup> knife which combines the abilities of `grep` and much more.

Just mark the lines starting with `srv` in a variable and soon after the requested pattern matches, print the last stored value in the variable

```
awk -v re="b1" '/^srv/{ line = $0; next } $0 ~ re { print line }' file
```

The above prints the whole line containing the `srv`, for the first column alone, do

```
awk -v FS="|" -v re="b1" '/^srv/{ line = $1; next } $0 ~ re { print line }' file
```

Not sure, if your intention is to print `..found on..` also, but you can do

```
awk -v FS="|" -v re="b1" '/^srv/{ line = $1; next } $0 ~ re { print re" found on " line }' file
```

Answering to OP's question about to case insensitive match for the pattern, you can use a special `awk` variable [`IGNORECASE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html) which can be enabled with the rest of the variables. But a word of caution as this causes all pattern matches in your code to be case insensitive. For specific matches alone do `toupper($0)` or `tolower($0)`

```
awk -v FS="|" -v re="b1" -v IGNORECASE=1 '/^srv/{ line = $1; next } $0 ~ re { print line }' file
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the search be case insensitive? such that if the user types A1 instead of a1 it still finds it?

Comment: @TimR use `tolower($0)` to ignore case, see my post.

Comment: @Inian I posted the way I have it set, not sure why the IGNORE case is not working.

Comment: @TimR: Your code posted when ran as `awk -v rs="A1" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/^srv/{ line = $0; next } $0 ~ rs { print rs" found on " line }'` works exactly as expected on GNU Awk 4.1.4. Check your version

Comment: or use `toupper($0) ~ rs` or `toupper($0) == rs`

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is your friend here.

```
awk -F'|' -v srch="$term" -v srvr="" '
    $1 ~ /^srv/{srvr=$1;next} 
    $1 == srch {print srch " found on " srvr}
' file
```

You can set the variable `term` in your script and then pass it to `awk` as follows:

**Example Use/Output**

Using your input file in `file`, you would have:

```
$ term=b1; awk -F'|' -v srch="$term" -v srvr="" '
>     $1 ~ /^srv/{srvr=$1;next}
>     $1 == srch {print srch " found on " srvr}
> ' file
b1 found on srv-test-2
```

and for `a1`:

```
$ term=a1; awk -F'|' -v srch="$term" -v srvr="" '
>     $1 ~ /^srv/{srvr=$1;next}
>     $1 == srch {print srch " found on " srvr}
> ' file
a1 found on srv-test-1
a1 found on srv-test-2
```

There are a number of variations, but this is the basic approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler  `gnu awk` version.

Setting Record Selector to `srv` and make this a block of text, search for pattern and print line number one.

```
awk -v f='b1' -v RS='srv' '$0~f {print f,"found in",RS$1}' file
b1 found in srv-test-2
```

```
awk -v f='a1' -v RS='srv' '$0~f {print f,"found in",RS$1}'
a1 found in srv-test-1
a1 found in srv-test-2
```

To ignore case

```
awk -v f='a1' -v RS='srv' 'tolower($0)~f {print f,"found in",RS$1}'
a1 found in srv-test-1
a1 found in srv-test-2
```